# Should I inform my referee about my applying result even I get rejected?

Tags: application

My referees tell me to inform them the result once I know. Should I still inform them if I get rejected? I don't want to disappoint them.

Comment: Yes, why not? Give them the courtesy of informing them if they asked. What's worse, facing a bit of embarrassment/disappointment or giving the people who have done you a favour and given you a reference total radio silence?

Comment: Yes. They deserve to know, given the effort they put in for you. They will probably respond by offering you some encouragement.

Comment: Getting rejected is probably one of the most common things academics do.

Answer (score 3):

You should tell them the result of your application. If the result happens to be negative, briefly tell them about your next step (e.g. will you apply to the same thing again in the future? what do you plan on doing until then?). They may even suggest a next step.

If you don't inform them of a negative result right away, they will find out if you eventually ask them for a second reference letter. Furthermore, since they explicitly asked you to tell them the result, it would be impolite to not.